How to create a conditional relationship for a column?
I have a school which runs different classes during summer and winter.
ClassroomSetup 1 & 2 have parallel data structure.
Every day has a switch to set the classroom setup. So when switch == 1, the school has classroomSetup1, when I call the related Teacher object which is 1-to-1 relationship with Classroom, the TeacherSet1 data will be achieved.
When the switch == 2, then, the ClassroomSetup1 object will be ignored, only ClassroomSetup2 and TeacherSet2 objects will be chained up when called.
How to achieve this data model in Power BI?
ps. I am here only simplying my scenario. The actual situation is like the latter attached picture
I have a long chain of related tables, and each table has a lot of columns to map with the switch. Is it possible to avoid creating a new columns for all chained tables and multiple columns of each table?



ClassroomSet1 & 2 should be the same table. So should TeacherSet.

i know what you mean. but it's complicated. they are all interrelated. i'm only simplifying the situation here.
